# Twitter doesn’t auto shorten the url?

Tags: javascript, url, twitter

I'm trying to create a “Tweet” button without loading additional scripts from Twitter, e.g. just with url parameters. For some reason url for share is not being shortened.

E.g.
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Text&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Do I need some third-party JS from Twitter to auto-shorten it?

Update: I ran it on the localhost: Twitter seems to detect localhost links. It works fine on the real tweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL will be shortened by Twitter when the Tweet is posted, but it will be displayed in full in the Tweet box / web intent, and in the final Tweet itself.